# subscript format the last character in a string in jquery

Tags: jquery, formatting

Is there a relatively simple way in jquery to format the last character in a string as subscript using the ID tag. I have a dynamic table and some of the cells contain a string of a letter first and a number last and would like to display the number subscript. So the value B1 at '#B1' should be display as B <sub>1</sub>.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t = "B1";
lastNumber = t.substr(t.length-1);
allCharsButLastNumber = t.slice(0, -1)
document.getElementById(t).innerHTML = allCharsButLastNumber+"<sub>"+lastNumber+"</sub>";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hm2vpvcq/